# Swift 5.5 async awaitを使ってのhttp GETはこれが最適解ですか？

Tags: swift

### Swift 5.5 async await

ベータ版であるXcode 13をインストールして、`Swift 5.5 async await`を勉強して、`http GET`を実装してみたのですが、これが最適解ですかね？

```swift
import Foundation

class API {
    func httpGet(for urlString: String) async throws -> Data? {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

        return data
    }
}

class Sample {
    var data : String?
    
    func getData() {
        async {
            let api = API()
            guard let data = try await api.httpGet(for: "https://api.isevenapi.xyz/api/iseven/6/") else { return }
            if let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(dataString)
                self.data = dataString
            }
        }
    }
}


var sample = Sample()

sample.getData()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まだ仕様も100%固まっていない新機能で、ベストプラクティスと言ったものも確立していないので、「これが最適解ですか」という質問に答えられる人は少ないと思います。以下もあくまで一個人の見解として。

---

- 異常系以外では非nilの結果が得られるので、戻り値をOptionalにする必要はないのではないか
- `getData()`で起動された処理の完了が通知されず、いつ`data`に正しい値が入るのかわからない

またXcode 13 betaの事情(と言うか、Apple/swift.org側の事情)ですが、`async {...}`はXcode 13 beta 3 では deprecated となっています。

私なら`getData()`も`async`にして、以下のような感じに書くでしょう。

```
import Foundation

class API {
    enum Errors: Error {
        case urlInvalid
    }
    
    func httpGet(for urlString: String) async throws -> Data {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            throw Errors.urlInvalid
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

        return data
    }
}

class Sample {
    enum Errors: Error {
        case encodingInvalid
    }
    
    func getData() async throws -> String {
        let api = API()
        let data = try await api.httpGet(for: "https://api.isevenapi.xyz/api/iseven/6/")
        guard let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
            throw Errors.encodingInvalid
        }
        return dataString
    }
}

Task {
    do {
        let sample = Sample()
        let result = try await sample.getData()
        print(result)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: 以下を参考にしたのですが、`async `...}`はdeprecatedなんですね。https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132

Comment: @zunda さん、そうですね。WWDCのセッションビデオは「ビデオ作成時の非公開ベータ版」を元に作成されていて、最終的にリリース版では細部の仕様が変更になることはちょくちょくあります。ベータ版の段階でdeprecatedになったAPI等はリリース版ではさっくり削除されるのが普通なのでご注意ください。